# ネストされてるJSONのデータを取得したい

Tags: android-studio, json

AndroidStudioでJSONデータの取得を試みているのですが、ネストされた情報のkeyの取得方法がわかりません。

```
{
  "ask": 418.79,
  "bid": 418.35,
  "last": 418.66,
  "high": 418.83,
  "low": 417.1,
  "open": {
      "day": "417.73",
      "week": "408.74",
      "month": "439.27"
  }
}
```

例えば上記のようなJSONデータの場合、"open"の"day"の値を取得するにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？
"last"などネストされていない値は下記のようにして取得できました。

```
String price = response.getString("last");
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「AndroidStudioで」とありますが、「AndroidStudioで開発しているAndroidアプリで」でしょうか?それともAndroidStudio用のプラグインか何かでしょうか?また単に「JSONデータ」とありますが、そのJSONデータはどうやって取得してどのように保持されているのでしょうか?少なくとも`response`のデータ型が何なのか、できればJSONデータ全体をとってきている部分全部のコードを示してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response`が`org.json.JSONObject型`ならば[getJSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String))で取得可能です。

```
String day = response.getJSONObject("open").getString("day");
```